# Copying data values only in a cell

Tags: vba, excel

Anybody knows how to copy the data in a cell, excluding its formats? Like the data itself is the only value that will be copied. I've tried these but is not working.

```
src.Range("F" & i).Copy Destination:=dest.Range("E" & destRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

And I have to parse also the data inside `src.Range("F" & i)` since it contains date and time values but I have to copy the date only. Any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really don't have to copy paste when you only want the data in a cell. All you have to do here is convert data to desired format and assign to the cell.

```
dest.Range("E" & destRow) = CDate(Format(src.Range("F" & i).Value, "MM/DD/YYYY"))
```

**EDIT**:

Try this:

```
dest.Range("E" & destRow) = src.Range("F" & i)
dest.Range("E" & destRow).NumberFormat = "MM/DD/YYYY"
```

Comment: The both of you's answer works the same. But the time is only converted into `00:00`. Any way to remove that?

Comment: @ramedju - That's because `dest.Range("E" & destRow)` is formatted that way.

Answer (score 1):

```
dest.Range("E" & destRow) = DateValue(src.Range("F" & i))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the **NumberFormat** of the cell:

`Range("E" & destRow).NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"`

**EDIT**

The value itself **won't** change. You could "cut" the value:

```
Left(Range("E" & destRow).Value, 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

The rawest information you can get from a [Range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx) is the [Range.Value2 property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193553.aspx); this will effectively return a double since your cell contains both date (integers) and time (fractions of an integer, a double). Strip off the decimal portion of the .Value2 by casting it as an integer.

```
dest.Range("E" & destRow) = Int(src.Range("F" & i).VALUE2)
dest.Range("E" & destRow).numberformat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
```

Get it back as a date in the displayed format you want with the [Range.NumberFormat property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196401.aspx).

Note that this is similar to another answer but the time is actually stripped out of the cell value, not left there but not displayed.